# CSS/HTML fixed position element resizing when browser resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

This is my situation: I have a table with table header `position: fixed` and a couple of table body rows with their width set to `100%`.

I am trying to make the header row resize properly when browser resizes, so its cells lines up body row cells.

How am I going to achieve that? (trying to make a `position: fixed` element react to browser size-change dynamically)

Here is my code. A very simple webpage

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body{
        width:100%;
    }
    thead{
        position:fixed;     
        width:100%
        overflow:visible;
        align:center;
    }
    th{
        border:2px solid black;
            width:20%;
            text-align:center;
    }

    td{
        border:2px solid black;
        width:20%;
        text-align:center;
    }
    table{
        width:80%;
        margin:auto;
        margin-top:50px;
    }
    .empty{
        height:30px;
    }
    .empty td{
        border:none;
    }


</style>

</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>
                heading1;
            </th>
            <th>
                heading2;
            </th>
            <th>
                heading3;
            </th>
            <th>
                heading4;
            </th>
            <th>
                heading5;
            </th>
        <thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="empty">
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    cell1;
                </td>
                <td>
                    cell2;
                </td>
                <td>
                    cell3;
                </td>
                <td>
                    cell4;
                </td>
                <td>
                    cell5;
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    cell1;
                </td>
                <td>
                    cell2;
                </td>
                <td>
                    cell3;
                </td>
                <td>
                    cell4;
                </td>
                <td>
                    cell5;
                </td>
            </tr>
        <tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm developing a website tool using ASP.net currently. Any solution in ASP.net will be much appreciated.

Comment: `align: center;` is deprecated.

Comment: Is there a reason the table's header position is fixed?  Do you want it to have a fixed header so you can scroll the rest of the table?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/light/

Comment: Keeping the header at the same place is useful when the table is longer than the screen vertically, so it is easier for the user to see the column header when they scroll down the table.

Answer (score 0):

The table element is not quite flexible as other in the html. Aparently the 'position:fixed' property will make the table ignore the width specification.

Therefore I tweaked your html and css a bit, in order to better divide the document's parts into header and content (section).

Basically, the header will contain only the table head.
The section will contain all the table rows and data in it. When scrolling, the header element will remain fixed and the table head cells in it (which has been given the exact same css attributes as the td cells) will remain perfectly aligned with their respective columns.

Hope this helps, good luck.

```css
    body {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    header {
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        margin-top: -30px;
    }

    section {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    table {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }

    header table th,
    section table td {
        width: 20%;
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px solid black;
    }
```

```html
    <header>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>heading1;</th>
                <th>heading2;</th>
                <th>heading3;</th>
                <th>heading4;</th>
                <th>heading5;</th>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </header>

    <section>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>cell1;</td>
                    <td>cell2;</td>
                    <td>cell3;</td>
                    <td>cell4;</td>
                    <td>cell5;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>cell1;</td>
                    <td>cell2;</td>
                    <td>cell3;</td>
                    <td>cell4;</td>
                    <td>cell5;</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be a decent approach to the problem.